If $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is an $\epsilon$-map between compact metric spaces then there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $diameter(f^{-1}(Z)) < \epsilon$
First a map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is called an $\epsilon$-map if it is continuous, onto and for any $y \in Y$, $diameter(f^{-1}(y)) < \epsilon$. Now I'm trying to find a $\delta > 0$ such that if $Z \subseteq Y$ is such that $diameter(Z) < \delta$, then $diameter(f^{-1}(Z)) < \epsilon $.
I'm a bit lost on how to do this. I don't see exactly how the hypothesis of $\epsilon$-map helps. It's clear that for $x,y \in f^{-1}(Z)$ if $f(x) = f(y)$ then $d(x,y) < \epsilon$. But in another case we would need something like $d(f^{-1}(x),f^{-1}(y)) < \epsilon$ and I don't know how we can get to this from the hypothesis. Any help would be appreciated.

It's an exercise from Nadler's Introduction to Continuum theory and it's a result used a couple of times throughout the book.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that no such $\delta$ existed. Then, for all natural numbers $N$, there exist sets $Z_n$ such that $\operatorname{diameter} Z_n < \frac{1}{n}$, but $\operatorname{diameter} f^{-1}(Z_n) \ge \varepsilon$.
Since diameter is preserved under closure, and
$$\operatorname{diameter} f^{-1}(\overline{Z}_n) \ge \operatorname{diameter} f^{-1}(Z_n) \ge \varepsilon$$
we may assume without loss of generality that each $Z_n$ is closed, and hence $f^{-1}(Z_n)$ is closed, by continuity. Note that the compactness of $X$ implies $f^{-1}(Z_n)$ is compact, hence the diameter is achieved by a pair of points. In short, there must exist $x_n, y_n \in f^{-1}(Z_n)$ such that $d_X(x_n, y_n) \ge \varepsilon$.
Using compactness, by taking multiple subsequences as necessary, we may assume without loss of generality that $x_n$ and $y_n$ converge to points $x, y \in X$ respectively.
Since $f(x_n), f(y_n) \in Z_n$, then
$$d_Y(f(x_n), f(y_n)) \le \operatorname{diameter} Z_n < \frac{1}{n}.$$
Since $f$ and $d_Y$ are continuous, this implies $d_Y(f(x), f(y)) = 0$, hence $f(x) = f(y)$. Let $z = f(x) = f(y)$. Note that $x, y \in f^{-1}(z)$.
However, since $d_X$ is continuous, we also have
$$\forall n \in \Bbb{N}, d_X(x_n, y_n) \ge \varepsilon \implies \varepsilon \le d(x, y) \le \operatorname{diam} f^{-1}(z).$$
This contradicts the assumption that $f$ is an $\varepsilon$-map.
